# How do I install MongoDB on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, mongodb

I am following this [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) on how to install mongoDB on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on my Raspberry PI 3 and I get the following error when I run "sudo apt-get update"

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'

Is there another way in which I can install MongoDB for Raspberry PI 3 on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raspberry PI 3 is a 64-bit ARM architecture, which is supported in MongoDB 3.4. The shell command you need to run to add the right repository for this architecture is:

```
 echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

Otherwise, I think instructions for installing MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04 should apply.

Answer (score 1):

You are following a guide for the desktop version of Ubuntu, therefore the repository you added is for a desktop CPU architecture, not the armhf architecture the Raspberry Pi needs. Try [this guide](http://andyfelong.com/2015/02/mongodb-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/) for Raspbian.

Comment: Will this guide for Raspbian work on MATE 16.04?